# sequelize error while syncing database - cannot find module bignumber.js

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js, node-mysql

I am using sequelize + mysql in my project.  I created a custom NPM module that contains sequelize models and provides some utility methods.  And I am using this custom NPM module in another nodejs module.  Since I am developing both modules in parallel, I am doing **npm link** to use the first module in the second.  All this works fine.

Recently, I switched to using npm install, instead of npm link, because I have to deploy both the modules together.  In this case, when I run 
**"node index.js** on the 2nd project, it gives an error that a module **bignumber.js** is not found.  Here is the output:

```
[2016-06-04 13:01:55.215] [INFO] campaign-service - Initializing Authorizer module...
[2016-06-04 13:01:55.329] [INFO] campaign-service - Successfully initialized Authorizer.
synchronizing with authentication database...  [FAIL]
error:  { [Error: Cannot find module 'bignumber.js'] code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND' }
Error while starting Authentication server:  { [Error: Cannot find module 'bignumber.js'] code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND' }
```

But the same thing works, if I use npm link, instead of npm install.

I googled up for bignumber.js not found errors, and followed the instructions which say that I need to explicitly install bignumber module, as found [here](https://github.com/felixge/node-mysql/issues/445) and [here](https://github.com/felixge/node-mysql/issues/412).  But still, it doesn't solve the problem.

Is this a problem of sequelize or mysql?  Any info on how to fix this...

Comment: Which version of node-mysql are you using? Those issues are very old, so it shouldn't be a problem any more. Have you tried re-installing node-mysql, something might have failed while installing its dependencies